# How to stop the user actions when webdriver is run?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, webdriver

I am using the selenium Chrome Driver to automate a process and also I want to restrict the user from clicking,scrolling or other suck events because the webdriver stops as soon the user performs such action.Do i need to use the JscriptDriver to add some javascript or is there any other way around?

Comment: Place an alert "Please take your hands out of the mouse".

Comment: Use PhantomJS, that way there is nothing to click on.